# What are "good" expected response times when processing large tables in MySQL remotely?

Tags: mysql

As i have never worked with large data remotely i have absolutely no idea about what is "slow" and what is "fast" when processing large tables in a remote server.

Say i have this table:

```
    'CREATE TABLE `kardex` (
      `kardexID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `codproduct` char(14) NOT NULL,
      `date` date NOT NULL,
      `reference` char(3) NOT NULL,
      `effect` char(1) NOT NULL,
      `priority` char(2) NOT NULL,
      `quantity` double(14,6) DEFAULT NULL,
      `numdocument` char(8) DEFAULT NULL,
      `serie` char(10) DEFAULT NULL,
      `subsidiary` char(2) NOT NULL,
      `subsidiary2` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
      `quant_entry` double(14,6) DEFAULT NULL,
      `cost_entry` decimal(12,2) DEFAULT NULL,
      `quant_egress` double(14,6) DEFAULT NULL,
      `cost_egress` decimal(12,2) DEFAULT NULL,
      `quant_balance` double(14,6) DEFAULT NULL,
      `cost_balance` decimal(12,2) DEFAULT NULL,
      `cost_average` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL,
      `costentry` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL,
      `production` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
      `numdocument2` char(15) DEFAULT NULL,
      `consume` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
      `lot` char(6) DEFAULT NULL,
      `nameprovider` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
      `nation` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
      `transaction` char(3) DEFAULT NULL,
      `productserie` char(16) DEFAULT NULL,
      `user` char(15) DEFAULT NULL,
      `regdate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      `pcname` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
      UNIQUE KEY `kardexID` (`kardexID`),
      KEY `codproduct` (`codproduct`,`date`,`priority`),
      KEY `sucprod` (`subsidiary`,`codproduct`,`date`,`priority`),
      KEY `codrefdatsub` (`codproduct`,`reference`,`date`,`subsidiary`),
      KEY `subdatref` (`subsidiary`,`date`,`reference`),
      KEY `subrefdatdoc` (`subsidiary`,`reference`,`date`,`numdocument`),
      KEY `productserie` (`productserie`),
      KEY `sepdatpri` (`serieproduct`,`date`,`priority`),
      KEY `num_document` (`numdocument`,`serie`,`reference`),
      KEY `prodsub` (`codproduct`,`subsidiary`),
      KEY `sepsub` (`productserie`,`subsidiary`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=88109 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'
```

Registering every single movement of 8,000 products so it contains 5,000,000 rows. To calculate the average cost of every product at a given range of dates id need to do a query to iterate and get the last calculated average before the starting date from the selected range. From there on, i have to calculate the average cost based off some registries from documents i know affect the average AND THEN update that row, so there can be several hundreds of thousands of UPDATES and a few thousand selects (because of the products).

This, locally, can be done in a few minutes. What should i expect it to be "slow" or "fast" in a remote server?

Comment: If you write the queries and updates so they all execute at the server rather than dragging thousands or millions of rows to the client and evaluating it all there, it should be acceptably fast. The essential thing is not to move the data if you don't have to.

Comment: @EJP How would i do that for a procedure like the one i mentioned? would you mind showing me an example?

Comment: I'm not sure this counts as large data.  5,000,000 rows is relatively small, only a few hundred MB.  You don't want to move this across the wire, but it is quite manageable in the context of the server.  What makes this amenable to a "big data" solution is that the computation must be performed against data that has low cardinality.  In that case, you might want to look at a bigdata solution, or at least consider big data principles such as do the work wher the data is residing.

Comment: I will have to do that then, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*It Depends.* In short: if the server is comparable in performance to your computer, then the only difference is going to be in how long it takes to transmit the result set. If the result set is large, it will be slower. If the result set is small, then it doesn't matter.

Whether (and what) is "slow" or "fast" is going to largely depend on three factors: the MySQL server itself, the connection between the client and the server, and the query that's run. In general, if a query is "slow" locally, it is *probably* going to be "slow" when run on a remote server.

The data is all stored on the server, and is processed there. How fast (or slowly) *processing* your query is depends on the data, the server, and the query. (Faster servers are usually faster; more data is usually slower.) All the work happens on the server; your local MySQL client is just a tool to talk to it and view results of queries.

When you query a local (same computer or same network) server, the time to transmit data is *usually* negligible, and for a small result set, basically doesn't matter. When you query a remote server, round-trip latency and bandwidth limitations apply. But if the result set is small, then the difference will be negligible. If the result set is huge, the difference can be significant.

For example: If you have a simple query with a large result set (such as a `SELECT *` from your 5 million row table), the time to process the query itself might be relatively small compared to the time it takes to transmit 5 million rows. (Reading 5 million rows from disk is generally *much* faster than sending that data across the internet.)

Alternatively, If you run a highly analytical query that returns a one-column one-row  integer result, the server could spend ages calculating the result and almost no time actually sending it to you once it's finished.

Comment: Excuse the, probably, silly question but, a table having 5 million rows should be few hundreds MB, Does that mean that if i  do a SELECT * it will transfer those hundreds MB through the net?

Comment: if you do a SELECT * it will transfer those hundreds MB through the net